# ExtJS 4.1.0 get the column Index

Tags: extjs

```
{
                    text: "current",
                    renderer:function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIndex ){  
                        return record.data.Resource[(colIndex-6)/2].current;
                 },
                    editor:{
                        xtype:'numberfield',
                        listeners:{
                            change:{
                                fn:function(me, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
                                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                                   //here I want to get the index of current column
                                   // form._record.data.Resource[colIdx].current=newValue;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In the function of event 'change' I want to get the index of my column where is my editor then the current column.
the word current is the name of my column.
and here my example :http://jsfiddle.net/D5UsU/32/

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see an elegant solution right now (though I doubt it is possible without overrides or thick derived classes). As a quick workaround I would suggest to mark your subcolumns with some additional field, say "subcolumn". Then you will be able to read it and identify which subcolumn triggered the change event:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    subcolumn: 1,
    listeners: {
        change: function (me, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            // use me.subcolumn here
        }
    }
}
```